# facebook php graph api me/friend reture nothing

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hi I'm a facebook api php developer. I developed some apps with  me/friend . now this return friends only for my admin account. when another user use this app, it retune nothing.

1. why this return friends only for my admin account.
2. if should I get special permission how can I get it.

could you any one please help me.

Comment: You will need to share some of your Code, or else it's unlikely that someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Make app live
You need to make the app and all its live features available to the general public. This can be done by making the app live by going to https://developers.facebook.com, select Apps --> Your App Name --> 'Status & Review'.

Login Review
You might need to do a Login review.
Review is not required to ask for the three basic permissions: public_profile, user_friends and email. In order to use Facebook Login in your app and access additional elements of a person's Facebook profile, you will need to submit your app for review. If your app is not approved or you don't submit for review, people will not be able to use Facebook Login in your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook Graph API for [Friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends) you need `user_friends` permissions which states that:

> Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app.
>
> Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.

[Read change log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0)

You can debug [me/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends&version=v2.5) endpoint as well.